# How do I give docker permissions to execute a file outside of a container?

Tags: java, docker, kotlin

I have an application on a spring-boot. The essence of the application is simple: using the first end-point I load a file with docker-compose.yml, using the second end-point I execute shell script "docker-compose up".

Of course I have volume mapping of the folder to an external system.

And when I have the application running on the local computer - everything works great. But when I wrap the application in a docker container, the application doesn't see the file when executing it. That is, it loads the file fine, but can't execute, citing that the file doesn't exist.

My guess is that the docker doesn't have enough permissions to read or execute the shell script. Am I thinking correctly and if so, how can this be resolved?

p.s. If anything, docker-compose to raise the container just with postgres+pgadmin. It doesn't really matter, just thought I'd clarify that this file is not for this spring application.

Comment: A Docker container can't read files or run executables that aren't in the container.  You need a _lot_ of permissions to be able to run Docker commands, and I'd be very very careful around security concerns and denial-of-service attacks as you've described this.  Can you rearchitect this setup to not need to dynamically launch containers?

Comment: @DavidMaze I think so. I can just run this application as a jar file without a docker. Just wanted to have everything packed : -(
Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: As you in essence want to perform the start of additional containers you should investigate integrating with the docker api from the java application instead of executing shell scripts that call the docker api.

Comment: ...I see you tagged this with both [tag:docker] and [tag:kubernetes] as well.  Another thing to keep in mind here is that you can't usually run any sort of `docker` command in Kubernetes; in Kubernetes there is a separate API system you'd need to integrate into.  That's another layer of complication you'd prefer to avoid.